# Is it possible to find the values of MySQL variables if I do not have SELECT privileges on mysql.user?

Tags: mysql, permissions, configuration

I am getting a 'msyql server has gone away' error sometimes when doing a large binary insert, so I wanted to check the settings on mysql, things like `wait_timeout` and `max_allowed_packet`. However

```
show create table mysql.user
```

returns

```
[Err] 1142 - SELECT command denied to user '557574_prod'@'96.25.95.162' for table 'user'
```

I'd rather not hit up tech support whenever I want to know some of the relevant settings, so I was wondering if there might be a workaround?

Comment: Can you do: `show variables like 'wait%';`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do things like these:

SHOW VARIABLES;

SHOW GRANTS;

Show status;