# MySQL: What exact commands does each privilege level allow?

Tags: mysql, select, permissions

I am configuring some new logins for users who have already been using the relevant MySQL servers under other logins. I would like to limit their privileges to the minimum each user needs, based on their input and reviewing the logs of what commands they have been executing. I would therefore like to know exactly what commands are allowed by each grantable privilege.

The [specification in MySQL's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html) provides some insight beyond the obvious (e.g. "The SELECT privilege enables you to select rows from tables in a database.") but it seems like the information given there is not exhaustive. For example, I see in the logs that a user with only `Select_priv` enabled also used `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SET` but I don't see any documentation of those commands being included in the `SELECT` privilege.

[This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2958/53784) and [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/66584/53784) give clues that there is more to the privileges than their names would directly imply.

**UPDATE:** @Colin 't Hart's comment is informative in that it explains the ability to execute `SHOW` and `SET` regardless of privileges. So my question should be limited to server side commands. I.e. **Are there commands not listed in the specification which can be used by users with a given privilege?**

Comment: `show` and `set` are commands of the MySQL client; you can't prevent users from using them. `set global` is only allowed if the user has `super`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-privileges

Comment: OK, I see my fundamental misunderstanding of command scope. Can you confirm then, that the "SELECT" privilege allows only that server side command and no other?

Comment: Yes, that's what it says here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_select

Answer (score 1):

`show` and `set` are commands of the MySQL client; you can't prevent users from using them.

`set global` is only allowed if the user has the `super` system privilege. See dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-privileges

Answer (score 1):

The [specification provided in the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html) gives most of the information on what abilities each privilege type enable, but it needs to be supplemented by other sources to get a comprehensive picture of what each privilege level allows.

Here are some examples from *[Managing and Using MySQL](https://books.google.com/books?id=kVB1wiF87ooC)*, pp. 100-102, that are not apparent from the docs:

- `PROCESS` allows `KILL SQL`.
- `ALL PRIVILEGES` does not allow `FILE`, `PROCESS`, `RELOAD`, `SHUTDOWN`, or `GRANT`.
- `SELECT` and `DELETE` together allow `REPLACE`.